# Close all activities before starting an activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented GCM in my application and as per the payload received from server I am starting an activity call it Activity(B).

My requirement is if I receive that particular payload from server while using the application and suppose I am on Activity (A) that time it(A) should close and only the Activity(B) should be in the instance of that application all stacked activity should be closed as soon as the activity B starts from my GCMIntentService class of GCM.

Things I had tried but did not work.

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(myContext,ActivityB.class);
myIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

I had also tried the flag

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

with all combination .

but no luck.Let me know if there is any possibilities that I am wrong somewhere in the manifest while declaring the activities I am not using any special parameters like launchMode or something in my Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to launch the root activity of your application (ie: the one that has `ACTION=MAIN` and `CATEGORY=LAUNCHER` in the manifest) with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RootActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("launchActivityB", true);
```

This will clear all activities from any existing task and start a new instance of `RootActivity`. In `RootActivity.onCreate()` add the following code (after the call to `super.onCreate()`:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("launchActivityB")) {
    // We have been started so that we can launch ActivityB, finish and do that now
    finish(); // End this activity right now
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return; // do no further processing in this activity
}
```

NOTE: The reason that trying to launch `ActivityB` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` doesn't do what you wanted is because of the way `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` works. It clears all activities from the existing task **that are sitting on top of (in front of) an existing instance of the activity you are trying to launch (in this case `ActivityB`)**. Since you didn't have an existing instance of `ActivityB` in your task, this flag didn't do anything.

Comment: I got you. But i have many activities that can be the root actiivity X,Y,Z in my case so how can i find that on which activity user is currently on so that i can fire a intrnt for that and finish it before starting the ActivityB. Will the launching of main activity finsh all the activities above it ?

Comment: If you are considering only the main activity as root then it is only one. Actually as per answer i thought you are considering the activity user is currently on as root activity. SO will the launching root activity clear all from stack of the application right?

Comment: Yes, I mean the activity used to **start the application**. That is the "root activity". If you launch that then it will bring any existing task with your application to the foreground and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will remove all the activities that are on top of that.